# Get properties of object by keys .NET Core and put in different object

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have empty `var filters = new Ranges();` object which has properties like:

```
 public class Ranges
{
    public double[] NumberOfCustomers { get; set; }

    public int[] NumberOfTransactions { get; set; }
    // ... more properties....
 }
```

each property in this object has to have two values: min and max which I get through sql query.
Since I get all min/max values in one query I put them in an object which results look like:

[image]

there are two values by each key and I want to add them two appropriate array in `Ranges` properties:

this is how I try that:

```
            var filters = new Ranges();
            PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(Ranges).GetProperties();
            foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
            {
                var title = property.Name;
                var a = rangeTask.Result; // IEnumerable<object>
                PropertyInfo pi = a.GetType().GetProperty(title);
                var value = pi.GetValue(a, null);
                property.SetValue(filters, value); // property of Ranges
            }
```

however the value I get is null. What I am doing wrong? How do I achieve getting these values?

Comment: i think ``pi.GetValue(pi, null)`` should be `pi.GetValue(a, null)`

Comment: If `a` is `IEnumerable<object>` I'm greatly surprised that this does not fail in runtime). Also `pi.GetValue(pi, null)` looks very wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few errors in your code. Assuming that `rangeTask.Result` is displayed on your screenshot you can try to do something like this:

```
var filters = new Ranges();
var a = new[] {KeyValuePair.Create("NumberOfCustomers", (object)0.0), KeyValuePair.Create("NumberOfCustomers", (object)100.0)}; // rangeTask.Result
PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(Ranges).GetProperties();
foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
{
    var title = property.Name;
    // get values by title 
    var values = a.Where(kvp => kvp.Key == title)
        .Select(kvp => kvp.Value)
        .OrderBy(v => v)
        .ToArray(); 

    // convert object[] to property type array
    var arr = Array.CreateInstance(property.PropertyType.GetElementType(), values.Length); 
    Array.Copy(values, arr, values.Length);

    // assign array
    property.SetValue(filters, arr); // property of Ranges
}
```